# how to implement threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading

i created a mobile operator, it sends number to server,,i added an thread, but it shows me 0 all the time, what do I need to do to increment my Thread, to be like> first time> Thread - 0, second time> THread-1 and so on. Like in the img[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtIpG.png)
My Code :

```
package PPC4;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Random;
public class Client extends Thread {
    Client() {
      // The compiler creates the byte code equivalent of super ();
    }
    Client(String name) {
        super (name); // Pass name to Thread superclass
    }
    public static Socket socket;

    public void run() {
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        String host = "localhost";
        int port = 25000;
        try {            
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            socket = new Socket(address, port);
             //Send the message to the server

            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

            int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(999999);
            String number = "069"+randomInt;
            String sendMessage = (number+1) + "\n";
            bw.write(sendMessage);
            bw.flush();
            System.out.println("The telephone number sent to the server: "+sendMessage);

            System.out.println ("The following user connected : " + getName ());
            //Get the return message from the server
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String message = br.readLine();
            System.out.print(" " +message);
        } catch(Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        {
            Client mt;
            if (args.length == 0)
                mt = new Client ();
            else
                mt = new Client(args[0]);
            mt.start ();
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't pass any arguments to your code, it will create thread named Thread-0 by default. If you pass at least one argument it will create thread with the name equalt to that argument.

Comment: where do i need to pass that argument?, i don't understand :(

Comment: @JohnCoffey see the code in your main method, the if statement? That mt = new Client(args[0]); means whatever is passed as arguments when program is started, it will be transferred to Client constructor. And in the Client constructor you set name of the thread.

Comment: sorry Ivan, just can you tell me what do i need to change?

Comment: mt = new Client(args[0]); in  mt = new Client(args[5]); ?

Comment: @JohnCoffey, no, the code is ok. When you start the program just type java Client MyName, or if you start from Eclipse please follow this http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/eclipseCommLineArgs.html